# Calling asmx via jquery gets wrong url

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, asmx

For a few days now I have been trying to get an ASMX webservice to work via jQuery.

Heres my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnTest").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown + ' ' + XMLHttpRequest); }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem seems to be that the browser checks for this url:

```
http://localhost:52657/WebService.asmx/CheckSmtp
```

When it should really check for this url:

```
http://localhost:52657/myappname/WebService.asmx/CheckSmtp
```

So I tried without the slash in the `$.ajax` url, but then it's worse, because if I'm on a page admin/products/edit then the ajax goes to `admin/products/edit/webservice.asmx` which is definitely wrong.

So how do I tell jquery to look in the root folder?

It may be that the problem is only on localhost, but I can't test anything this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will resolve the right url server side:

```
<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld")%>
```

Comment: thanks a million. actually meanwhlile someone sent me a tip of putting a label in the master page that gets its value server side to the root path. and it worked. but this technique fixed me a different problem . the src of the javascript wasnt either resolving correctly. i used ur answer and it works. thanks. amchoo?

Comment: ok. now i had the chance to use it in the url portion of the ajax contol. it works just dandy